# jquery toggle not working within if-else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide/show sections of a page using the following script:

```
$(function () {
    $('.open').on('click', function () {
        var contentType = $(this).attr('id');
        if (contentType == "all") {
            $('.content-div').show();
        } else if (contentType == "train" || "manual") {
            $('.content-div.' + contentType).show();
            $('.content-div:visible:not(.' + contentType + ')').hide();
        } else if (contentType == "close") {
            $('.content-div').hide();
        } else {
            $('.content-div.' + contentType).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

A [jsfiddle example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex1Hamilton/cgLnh5dy/8/) with html

The issue is with the final line in the else part - this works correctly (show/hide the relevant div(s) with the associated class) when outside the if-else statement but doesn't work in the else section - the div appears the first time a numbered button is clicked, but doesn't disappear on reclicking.

What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
} else if (contentType == "train" || "manual") {
```

with:

```
} else if (contentType == "train" || contentType == "manual") {
```

`"manual"` is always evaluated as `true` therefore this whole `else-if` branch is evaluated as `true`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) for more details.